# Move Google tasks from Gmail to Google Apps account

Tags: google-workspace, google-tasks

Is it possible to move Google tasks from Gmail to Google Apps account?

or

Is there any way to export the Google tasks from my Gmail and import it in Google Apps account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to export tasks. At best, you can email the task list to your Google Apps account and copy+paste, but again they become one big task instead of several, individual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a great, free, third-party solution for this. It's still in beta and not quite perfect yet, but gets the job done. In addition, it can sync task lists between accounts on a regular schedule - finally a way to share Google Tasks with others!

http://www.isynctasks.de/

A couple notes:

- You don't have control over how often it syncs, but it's roughly every 15 minutes. If you're just using it to move from one account to another, that shouldn't be a problem.
- It only syncs tasks that haven't been cleared (using "clear completed tasks" from the menu).

A huge thanks to [herr.kaste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526957/herr-kaste) for developing this!

Comment: I have no affiliation with the developer or site, aside from providing some feedback to him via email .