# Is it possible to "unclear" Google Tasks after you've cleared completed tasks?

Tags: gmail, google, google-tasks

In Google Tasks, after you've hit the "Clear completed tasks" button, is there any way to "unclear" the tasks? I'd like to leave them checked off, but return them to the main view with the unchecked tasks.

Please note that un-checking and then re-checking each task will not work for my situation, as doing so changes the "completed date" of the task. If you're curious, the reason I want to do this is so that I can get my entire task history (with meta data intact) from one Google account to another using the tool mentioned here: [Move Google tasks from Gmail to Google Apps account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15660/move-google-tasks-from-gmail-to-google-apps-account/40107#40107)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any answer on the web so I felt free to explore.  I saw that putting tasks as uncompleted and then marking them as completed UNCLEARS them.

I know it would be hard with a lot of tasks but didn't find another way. Best luck!

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work for my particular situation due to the "completed date" issue, but it appears there's no way to do what I was asking. For those that end up here when searching how to unclear tasks though, it's definitely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I use a particular task list for packing for trips. It's gotten quite extensive over the years. The only way I've found that keeps me from unchecking every task in my list is that I've created a handful of primary tasks, each of those contain many sub-tasks. So when I check the primary task it'll mark all of the sub-tasks as complete. Conversely when you uncheck a primary task it'll uncheck all the sub-tasks as well. So I have to uncheck 10+/- primary tasks rather than 100 tasks.

Comment: this would be nice, but didn't work for me in 2022 (8 yrs later -- feature removed by Google?)

Answer (score 0):

I was not so used to this until the Gmail has new design launched in 2018, Google Tasks was literally overshadowed by Google’s other primary features that time. Now it has really good features and these are very user friendly. There is one desktop app for Google Tasks, https://tasksboard.app/.

Go to Actions under Tasks then select Clear Completed Tasks. Unfortunately, it just hides them, but unless you select to view them again, they're out of sight.

Comment: Note: This app is not directly affiliated to Google